# Calculate the proportion between font-size and its container width

Tags: css, font-size

I am working on the relationship between the font size and the optimal width of the container they are in.
I know that the optimal line width for a single column of text ranges from 45 to 75 characters per line.

But there should also be a way to calculate the optimal width of the container of that text, and if I got it right "Line length should be around 30 times (between 20 to 40) the size of the font type".

In my case I have:

```
font-size: 2.488rem;
width: 55vw;
```

How do I change the width size to be proportionated to the font size?

Comment: Maybe try calc() function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc. 
Example of using calc() for fluid typographic: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fluid-typography. Anyway for very complex (declare words per line) calculations sometimes you need to use Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If your container is based on vw (viewport) you can do using `font-size: Xvw`, but if your container is based in px AFAIK you can't detect the width of it like that.

For vw values you can even use calc() with min and max value:

```
font-size: calc( [minFS]px + ([maxFS] - [minFS]) * (100vw + [minSS]px)/([maxSS-minSS]);
```

minFS - min font size

maxFS - max font size

minSS - min screen size

maxSS - max screen size

---

For example min font size 16px for 400px with max 24px since 800px:

```
font-size: calc( 16px - ( 24 - 16 ) * ( 100vw - 400px ) / ( 800 - 400 );
```

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/05/fluid-typography/